# Importing Excel sheets to existing Excel file works except for one thing

Tags: excel, vba

I want to import some sheets from a different Excel file to a target file and append these after the other sheets, using a VBA button. I've been looking into a few things and this comes closest to a solution. However, one problem remains, depending on how I put in one specific line (cf. commenting).

```
Private Sub Importer_Click()
    Dim directory As String
    Dim import As String
    Dim curr_file As String
    Dim source As Workbook
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim total As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    directory = "C:\Users\...\"
    import = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

    curr_file = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Do While import <> ""
        Set source = Workbooks.Open(directory & import)

        For Each sheet In source.Sheets
            total = Workbooks(curr_file).Worksheets.Count
            sheet.Copy After:=Workbooks(curr_file).Sheets(total)
        Next sheet

        Workbooks(import).Close ' alternative 1: works smooth, files close, but sheets are not added
        Workbooks(directory & import).close ' alternative 2: sheets are added, but importing files remain open (because the 'directory' is not needed in fact) + I get a runtime error 9 (subscript out of range)

        import = Dir()
   Loop

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I suppose the answer is simple (I'm relatively new to VBA). Who can help?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `source.Close SaveChanges:=True` ...?

Answer (score 1):

You set a workbook object to the **source** workbook as you opened it. Use this definitive object reference to close it and specify that changes should be saved.

```
source.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick. Nothing new happens. The curr_file is by the way the file who imports the Excel sheets, and the source file(s)/workbook(s) are the ones from which sheets are extracted. Any other suggestion of what could be wrong? I added message boxes to check the variables: the sheet names, as wel as Excel files and new number of total sheets seem to update well.